# Flutter - Getx Obx not updating a value from endpoint

Tags: flutter

I am working with an endpoint, where at each request I update the data. But for some reason that I don't know, the data is not updated.
The first request shows it correctly but if I make another different request it keeps the previous data in the view.

Controller:

```
class TiendaPedidosDetalleController extends GetxController {
  var pedidoId = 0;
  var numeroFactura = '0'.obs;
  UsersProvider usersProvider = UsersProvider();
  TiendaPedidosDetalleController() {
    pedidoId = Get.arguments['pedidoId'];
    pedidoDetalle(pedidoId);
  }

 void pedidoDetalle(pedidoId) async{
    ResponseApi responseApi = await usersProvider.pedidoDetalle(pedidoId);
    if (responseApi.success == true) {
      numeroFactura.value = '';
      numeroFactura.value = responseApi.data['id'].toString();
    } else {
      Get.snackbar('ERROR', responseApi.message ?? '');
    }
  }

}
```

View:

```
class TiendaPedidosDetallePage extends StatelessWidget {
  TiendaPedidosDetalleController con =
      Get.put(TiendaPedidosDetalleController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(),
      body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: Center(child: Text('Tu Ticket # ${con.numeroFactura.value}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),))),
            ],
          )
      ));
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you call pedidoDetalle() for another result?
and you see ERROR snackbar?

Comment: you need call numeroFactura.refresh()

Comment: @HosseinAsadi I call it from a page that is a list of orders, get the id and call the page with that argument. The endpoint works fine, even if I print the response it gets it correctly, but for some reason it doesn't update the variable numeroFactura.value.

Comment: @shjlone I've tried it as you say, but it doesn't work either

Comment: @Alberto these codes seem right, can you share the item list onTap?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the widget which contains your controller's variable to listen to its changes:

```
child: Obx(
              () => Text(
                'Tu Ticket # ${con.numeroFactura.value}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I have the Obx on top of everything in the Scaffold, but I have tried as you indicated and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I see. Have you tried Obx on Scaffold, then another Obx on the Text Widget? or maybe just 1 Obx only in the Text Widget